# How to find and erase lines inside a text file

Tags: sed, command-line, text-files, string-comparison

I have two text files:

`remove.txt`

```
red
green
blue
```

`collors.txt`

```
yellow
red
black
green
grey
blue
```

I want to remove the occurrences of `remove.txt` lines inside `collors.txt` and save it as `output.txt`. I tried using sed command inside a loop, but couldn't make it work.

Script:

```bash
remove='remove.txt'
input='collors.txt'
while read line; do
    # I failed to use sed here to do the job
done < $remove
```

Comment: `findstr /x /v /g:"remove.txt" "collors.txt">newfile.txt` should do that. See `findstr /?` from the prompt of many examples on SO for documentation.

Comment: Whilst you have used the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, which is almost exclusively for Windows, you have posted code written for a Unix based system. Did you incorrectly tag your question?

Comment: @Compo: as the author is into UNIX anyway, why not a simple `grep -v -f remove.txt colors.txt`? Wouldn't that do the trick? :-)

Comment: @Compo: yeah, sorry. I've removed [batch-file] tag now.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a Unix tool, `cmd` can do it itself:

```
findstr /v /x /g:remove.txt collors.txt > output.txt
```

See the output of `findstr /?` to learn about the switches

Output with your example files:

```
yellow
black
grey
```

Comment: Just a note Stephan: It seems more likely, based on the implication that the SEd code failed within the submitted BASH script, that the OP has incorrectly tagged their question, and they are using a 'nix shell.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#.*#/&/d#' removeFile | sed -f - coloursFile >outFile
```

Create a sed script from the removeFile and apply it to the coloursFile to produce the outFile. The created script will have a line like `/colour/d` for each line in the remove file where the `colour` will be replaced by `red` etc.

N.B. The `-f -` option applies the output from the previous pipe as an input sed script.

Comment: It worked with the files at my example. But failed when I tried using files containing a / character. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @CristianoAlmeida just change the delimiters i.e. `sed 's#.*#\\@&@d#' removeFile | sed -f - coloursFile >outFile`